# How to inspect the bytes contained in a "Foundation.Data" byte buffer in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, debugging, foundation

I'm having trouble getting Xcode to show me the underlying memory of a [`Foundation.Data`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data).

I'm parsing a binary format that's passed to my function  as a blob in a `Data`. In the debugger Xcode shows me this:

[image: "data" as I can view it in the debug panel]

I can control-click on any of those and choose 'View Memory of "data"' etc, but none of them show the memory block I'm looking for. (I know this because I `print()` the first few bytes accessed via the subscript operator `data[0]` etc.)

- `_representation` shows me address `0x0`
- `slice` (1) shows me memory but not what I'm looking for
- `slice` (2) shows me the same as the previous one
- `lowerBound` shows me the same as the previous two
- `upperBound` shows me some other memory not what I'm looking for
- `storage` shows me address `0x0`

I'm used to languages more like C where I'd have a pointer or array.

I've also tried stepping through the disassembly while viewing the registers where the code is indexing into the data but I'm not used to ARM asm and can't seem to find the address I'm looking for that way either.

(No, it's not the memory at `0x40006000022804b0`)

---

## desired behavior

View the bytes encapsulated by the `Data`

## specific problem or error

Every component of the `Data` that the debugger presents to me shows either nothing or bytes other than what I'm looking for when I use the context menu "View Memory of ..."

## and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem

This problem is not about my code. It's about how to get the Xcode debugger to show me the underlying memory of an object.

Comment: How is `data` created?

Comment: @Willeke: It's passed to me from parts of the GitHub project I'm not touching. That code is doing `if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "") { let data: Data? ; do { try data = Data.init(contentsOf: url)`

Comment: What is printed when you do Print description of "data"?

Comment: @Willeke I'm not sure what you mean. If I do `print(data)` it prints `41009 bytes`

Comment: Huh, this really is surprisingly difficult. For one, `Data` has multiple different backing storage strategies (e.g. one for slicing, one for bridging to Objective C, etc.) `0x40006000022804b0` contains a `Foundation.__DataStorage` object. It has a [`_bytes` property](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/62cc39c534b364cef242dc0ce75aec5bfe53e0fc/Sources/Foundation/Data.swift#L132) which is where the actual buffer is

Comment: @Alexander: It was also surprisingly difficult to get this accepted as a legit SO question! Let me test your solution...

Comment: @Alexander: Yes! I'm very new to Swift and Mac programming but can confirm your answer by doing `print((data as NSData).bytes)` and pasting the address into the memory viewer. If you'd like to submit an answer I will accept it.

Comment: In the Debug Area, right-click on `data` and select `Print description of "data"`.

Comment: @Willeke Wow you found it. At first glance I thought it was the same as in the screenshot, but while it was the same kind of nested types, the actual items are different and the one labelled `pointer` is the one I needed. I you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data` has multiple different backing storage strategies (e.g. one for slicing, one for bridging to Objective C, etc.)

`0x40006000022804b0` contains a `Foundation.__DataStorage` object. It has a [_bytes property](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/62cc39c534b364cef242dc0ce75aec5bfe53e0fc/Sources/Foundation/Data.swift#L132) which is where the actual buffer is. It's exposed `-[NSData bytes]`, which you can print out for debugging purposes

Comment: Now I want to do the same for a `ContiguousArray<UInt8>` and I'm finding it just as difficult, even after what I've learned from your answer.

Comment: @hippietrail https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray/withunsafemutablebytes(_:)

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments of [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) and [hippietrail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527702/hippietrail), `message.payload` is of type `Data`:

- Cast Data expression, i.c. `message.payload` to `NSData`
- get `bytes` property from it
- right-click on expression, select "Print description of (message.payload as NSData).bytes"
- copy the hexadecimal address printed
- Debug->Debug Workflow->View Memory
- Paste the copied address in the "Address" textbox and press return

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift Data Type

According to [Data.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/Data.swift), Swift `Foundation.Data` has 4 type:

- empty
- inline = `InlineData`
- slice = `InlineSlice`
- large = `LargeSlice`

#### Your case: InlineSlice

-> your here seem is: **InlineSlice**

-> your Data's memory layout (maybe):

- yourData(`InlineSlice`)

  - `Int32 slice`

    - `0x00009AE000000000`

      - `39648` == `0x9AE0`
  - `__DataStorage* storage`

    - `0x40006000022804b0`

##### `__DataStorage` detail

-> for `storage`=`__DataStorage`=`0x40006000022804b0`, its layout is:

```c
class __DataStorage {
    var isa: objc_class* // NULL for pure Swift class
    var refCount: UInt64
    var _bytes: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
    var _length: UInt64
    var _capacity: UInt64
    var _offset: UInt64
    var _deallocator: ((UnsafeMutableRawPointer, Int64) -> Void)?
    var _needToZero: Bool
}
```

you can check `__DataStorage` memory data detail via `lldb` command, eg:

```bash
x/8xg 0x40006000022804b0
```

#### Swift Data Memory Layout and Example

I have drawed a figure about Swift data memory layout and detailed example:

- online view

  - [Swift Data Memory Layout](https://www.processon.com/view/link/65d0cd7c28bf1d00d08a3cbc)
- local image

  - [image]
- core layout

  - [image]